# How to decode value in redis cli or shell script

Tags: bash, shell, utf-8, redis, redis-cli

I've written redis-cli bash script to process all key and value for bulk retrieval but values are not printing as expected. When I give my key in redis-cli its printing with all special characters:

My Key and output from redis-cli

```
redis-cli MGET "0124" "0016"
1) "\x1f\x8b\b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1d\x8e1\x0e\xc3@\b\x04?\x04\x0e8Q\x17\xa9\xf9\xdc\xdeY\x0b2\x91[\xfd>K\x99\xfd\xaf\xfc\x03\xeb-1\x10\xef\x00\x00\x00"
2) "\x1f\x8b\b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1d\x8e1\x92\x031\b\x04?\x04k\x84\x10\xa0\xf8\x1;\xa8-7\xbb\xa2> \xc0n\xdc\xe1\xce\xdb\xbdk\xac\x81\x9a]Q*\x8ex\xa4\xe0\x99\xd5\xd1\xb3\x94w^\x9f]\xa7$2\xce;\xdcp\x9c\x9b\xff;\xff\x01\xb3\xcc\xd5H\xf0\x00\x00\x00"
```

Can someone please help how to decode this value in redis-cli or shell script. 
I'm new to Redis - it would be really appreciated if you can help me to fix this issue

I used gunzip - but I'm getting below error:

```
redis-cli -h GET "100" | gunzip
```

**Error:**

```
   gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
   gzip: stdin: decompression OK, trailing garbage ignored
```

**Redis-cli code:**

```
#!/bin/sh
hostName=$1
port=$2
count=$3
cursor=-1
keys=""
recordCount=0
while [ $cursor -ne 0 ];
do
        if [ $cursor -eq -1 ]
        then
        cursor=0
    fi
    reply=`redis-cli -h $hostName -p $port SCAN $cursor MATCH "*" COUNT $count`
    cursor=`expr "$reply" : '\([0-9]*[0-9 ]\)'`
    keys=${reply#[0-9]*[[:space:]]}
    value=$(redis-cli -h $hostName -p $port MGET $keys)
    temCount=`echo $value | awk -F\| '{print NF-1}'`
    recordCount=`expr ${temCount} + ${recordCount}`
done
echo "Total no. of documents are: " $recordCount
```

**My Redis key-value pattern:**

```
Keys - 123.item.media
Values - 93839,abc,98,829|38282,yiw,282,282|8922,dux,382,993|

Keys - 234.item.media
Values - 2122,eww,92,211|8332,uei,902,872|9039,uns,892,782|

Keys - 839.item.media
Values - 7822,nkp,77,002|7821,mko,999,822|
```

Comment: echo -e "..." should do the trick.

Comment: I tried something like this     value=$(redis-cli MGET $keys)
    echo -e $value | gunzip . But it didn't work

Comment: What about `value=echo -e "$(redis-cli MGET $keys)" | gunzip` ?

Comment: I'm getting -e: command not found

Comment: sorry, `value=$(echo -e "$(redis-cli MGET $keys)" | gunzip)`

Comment: It says gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157728/discussion-between-learn-java-and-mr-bug).

Comment: @Mr.bug, `echo` is not *permitted to have* `-e` do anything but print the two-character sequence `-e` on output by the POSIX standard (this is one of very few places where bash is actually doing something the standard prohibits, rather than putting extensions in undefined space), and in some modes (when both `xpg_echo` and `posix` flags are set), bash *doesn't* offer said extension. Consider making a habit of using `printf '%b\n' "$value"` instead. See also http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, particularly the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections.